# Why this simple hibernate sample doesn't work?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote these two classes:

```
public class ClasseA {

    Integer id;
    String numero;
    ClasseB cb;

    public ClasseB getCb() {
        return cb;
    }

    public void setCb(ClasseB cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ClasseB {

    Integer id;
    String annotazione;

    public String getAnnotazione() {
        return annotazione;
    }

    public void setAnnotazione(String annotazione) {
        this.annotazione = annotazione;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

As you can see in ClasseA there is a reference to ClasseB.

this is the mapping:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="ClasseA" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="numero" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="numero"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one cascade="all" class="ClasseB" name="cb"/>
  </class>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="ClasseB" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="annotazione" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="annotazione"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Two things don't work as expected:

- First of all, since I'm using hdb2ddl with update I'd expect do generate a table for classeA with a reference to classeB (and of course a table for classeB). Which isn't. All I get is:

  CREATE TABLE `classea` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `numero` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

  CREATE TABLE `classeb` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `annotazione` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
- Second: If I save an istance of classeA with cb correctly set to a cb istance, it will work putting a row on the first and a row on the second table. But on retrivial it doesn't even load classeA....

Please help as I think I didn't understand properly this kind of association. Please don't suggest to use annotations as I can't. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding with one-to-one is that they share identity. That is, when you create a ClasseA, the ClasseB inside of ClasseA will have the same id. There is no explicit reference between the two tables.

For sanity, I often use many-to-one, even in the one-to-one scenario, because this creates the foreign key column in the database like you are expecting.

I'm not sure about the retrieval issue you are having without a little more information about the code being used to save and load.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Class B's id isn't properly associated to Class A. I assume you're associating the 2 classes by primary key. Then try this.

First, for one-to-one relationship, both classes need one-to-one mapping configured.

Add this to Class B's definition
(note: The constrained attribute is important to the hibernate schema generation tool.):

```
<one-to-one class="ClasseA" name="ca" constrained="true" />
```

Second, making sure your dependent class associate its id to Class A by using

```
<generator class="foreign">
```